# Is there any short way to slice an array from end to start without looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays

*For example I have this array*

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

And I wrote this code but it is long too. Can you help me to get a shorter solution.

```
array.map((e,i)=>array[array.length-1-i])
```

How can I reverse an array without using reverse method and using even shorter method than my code.

Comment: Use built in `.reverse()`.....`array.reverse()`

Comment: Did you try array.reverse()

Comment: I mentioned above that I have to get a solution without using built-in reverse method

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
//this is shorter but more expensive
const reverse = array.sort(x => -1);
console.log(...reverse);
//if you want to keep the original array intact, make a copy of the array and then sort it
//const reverse = [...array].sort(x => -1);
```

Comment: Bizarrely, if you try your code in older browsers, the order remains as 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @ATD, even if you change -1 to 1?

Comment: I tried that - the reverse happened.  ie, newer browsers now show 1, 2, 3, 4 and the older ones became 4, 3, 2, 1.  I've tried in FireFox 54 and SRWare Iron 57 - I'm not sure if it's an age thing or if these browsers do things differently as I can't install the latest versions of either to find out.  The other browsers I have - Vivaldi, Pale Moon, Chrome and Edge are up to date and your original code works fine on those.

Comment: Maybe try `true` or `false` instead of numbers?